Fixed points in Bruhat-Tits building of $\mathrm{GL}_2$
Let $F$ be a non-archimedean local field, and consider the Bruhat-Tits building $\mathcal B$ of $\mathrm{GL}_2(F)$. Does every $g \in \mathrm{GL}_2(F)$ admit a fixed point, i.e. $\mathcal B^g \ne \varnothing$?

My thought is the following. Suppose that $A \mathcal O_F^2$ is a lattice in $F^2$ where $\mathcal O_F$ is the ring of integers. Then the stabiliser of $A \mathcal O_F^2$ in $\mathrm{GL}_2(F)$ is $A \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathcal O_F) A^{-1}$. As the $\mathrm{GL}_2(F)$-action factors through $\mathrm{PGL}_2(F)$, the stabiliser of a vertex $[A \mathcal O_F^2]$ is
$$
\operatorname{Stab}_{\mathrm{PGL}_2(F)}([A \mathcal O_F^2]) = A \mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathcal O_F) A^{-1}.
$$
Thus it suffices to show that any given $g \in \mathrm{GL}_2(F)$ is conjugate to some matrix in $F^\times \cdot \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathcal O_F)$. Is this even true?
Added: I forgot about the case when $g$ swaps two incident vertices, i.e. when $\mathcal B^g$ consists of a midpoint of an edge.

When you say "any", do you mean "some" or "every?"

@MoisheKohan Sry, I mean every. I fixed this.

Based on the observation of @Alex B., the stabiliser of a lattice $[A \mathcal O_F^2]$ is $A F^\times \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathcal O_F) A^{-1}$. Since the fixed point set in a Bruhat-Tits tree is convex and since $g \in \mathrm{GL}_2(F)$ maps vertices to vertices, an element $g$ can only fix vertices, entire edges or midpoints of edges, in which case $g$ swaps neighbouring vertices. Thus, an element $g \in \mathrm{GL}_2(F)$ admits fixed points if and only if $g^2$ is conjugate to some element in $F^\times \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathcal O_F)$.
In fact, the counterexample mentioned by @Alex B. doesn't admit fixed points in form of midpoints of edges as well. One notices that $g 
= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ & \pi\end{pmatrix}$ for a uniformiser $\pi \in F$ acts by translating the standard apartment $[\mathcal O_F \oplus \pi^n \mathcal O_F]$, $n \in \Bbb Z$.

$\DeclareMathOperator{\PGL}{PGL}\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}\newcommand{\cO}{\mathcal{O}}$
First, note that since $\PGL_2(F)$ acts transitively on the vertices of the Bruhat–Tits tree, and since the stabiliser of the standard lattice class $[\cO^2]$ is $\PGL_2(\cO)$, the stabiliser of an arbitrary lattice class $\Lambda=[A\cO^2]$ is $A\PGL_2(\cO)A^{-1}$; in other words, your criterion is not just sufficient, but in fact necessary: an element of $\GL_2(F)$ fixes a point if and only if it is conjugate to an element of $F^\times\GL_2(\cO)$.
But note that the determinant of every element of $F^\times\GL_2(\cO)$ has even valuation, so the same is true of anything that is conjugate to such an element. Thus, for example the matrix $\pmatrix{p&0\\0&1}$ is not of this form, and therefore has no fixed points.

But what about $g$ swapping two vertices? My guess would be that this is only possible if the valuation of $\det g$ is odd.
